# Add packages to a Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm creating a servlet-based application using Tomcat.

Besides that i've some classes to acces a DB with jdbc. (present in a other folder/package)

I was asking myself how to integrate them cleanly in my servlet-based application.

What's the "cleanest" solution ?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with packaging as a separate JAR file and placing in `WEB-INF/lib` of your web app.

While it may seem easier to just put JAR to the common libraries folder so that  several web apps start using it - it will result in not being able to upgrade the JAR without restarting the whole server. Also you will need to make sure that the new JAR is working fine with all of the apps. Classpath issues are possible with this approach too.

Comment: addmiting i've a folder src with a Main.jar and two subfolders accesBD and model. How would you generate the jar ? I'm quite new at java.

Comment: That depends on the tools that you're using to build and package your application. There are hundreds of them, and this discussion is another question - not related to Tomcat but rather your tools.

Comment: I don't use anytool, just compiling with javac in the terminal.

Comment: Then you should use a tool. You should separate your DB access part from Main project into a separate sub-project, or a folder. There you compile it and use `jar` tool to produce a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Package them in jar files and then add files to you're project.